# Сравнение вводимого слова с файлом

Tags: python, if

У меня в файле есть слово `example`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после того, как пользователь вводит слово, оно сравнивалось со словом в файле. Если правильно, вывести `1`, если нет -  `0`.

Мой код выводит всегда `0`. Надеюсь на помощь.

Вот код:

```py
rd = open('admin.txt', 'r')

nick = input('Введите имя:')
x = rd.readlines()
name = x[0]
print(name + nick)
if name == nick:
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)

rd.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в `name` есть символ перевода строки, а в `nick` его нет. Избавиться от него можно так

```
name = x[0].strip()
```